# Where can you play against AlphaZero?

Tags: engines, websites, alphazero

I have read a few articles about the game between Stockfish and AlphaZero. But is there a place where anyone can play against AlphaZero?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As already explained by other answers, AlphaZero itself is not publicly available.

The community has created [Leela Chess Zero](https://lczero.org/), a chess engine that started by using the same basic concepts as AlphaZero, but has since seen many additional improvements. It's probably stronger than AlphaZero ever was. Their site has [a page](https://lczero.org/play/online/) on how to play against it, either download it or play against one of the lichess bots.

As a side note, stockfish has also been improving steadily (mainly with the introduction of [NNUE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiently_updatable_neural_network)), so it should now also be able to beat the original AlphaZero version again.

Comment: On what grounds do you base your remark that it probably is stronger than AlphaZero? Has there been a series of 100 games of Leela against the old stockfish version that shows leela also didn't lose a single time and won > 25%? Or is there some kind of rating that can be computed?

Comment: @CarloWood The big A0 vs SF8 match was [1000 games with 155 wins and 6 losses](https://www.chess.com/news/view/updated-alphazero-crushes-stockfish-in-new-1-000-game-match), which comes to +52 elo. A bit later [SF11](https://stockfishchess.org/blog/2020/stockfish-11/) was released with +150 elo compared to SF8. Currently in the [CCC](https://www.chess.com/computer-chess-championship) LC0 is only slightly worse then SF14, which should by now be much stronger than SF11 was. I think it's pretty safe to conclude from this that both SF and LC0 are stronger than A0 was.

Comment: @CarloWood see this question: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29791/which-is-better-stockfish-10-or-alphazero It's been over another year since I wrote that answer, and SF 15 dev has gained significant strength over SF 11, which was the version at the time.

Comment: @ToddSewell How did you conclude that A0 was 52 elo above SF8? Is there some formula for calculating that based on the number of wins, draws and losses?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye You can calculate this using the definition of Elo [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Theory), or more conveniently using an online calculator, I like [this one](https://3dkingdoms.com/chess/elo.htm).

Answer (score 13):

No, you can't play against [AlphaZero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaZero), unless you get a special access from [DeepMind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeepMind).

Answer (score 13):

According to [this website](https://www.chess.com/terms/alphazero-chess-engine), AlphaZero was one of the strongest chess engine and defeated Stockfish (28 victories, 72 draws, and no losses). It runs on Google's supercomputer and is developed by DeepMind. There is no website which currently supports this type of chess engine. As discussed on the answer above, you'll have to get special permission from DeepMind to play against it. So, the answer is no. Read the article that I've linked on the top of this post for more information about its history, development, and impact in the chess world.